# Vertical alignment of text in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have two images in two different column in a table and in the third table i want to have a text, ideally as a list, but when i write the text it begins at the last row and goes down from there, i want to have the text start from the top. 
Here is the code

```
    \begin{tabular}{c c |p{0.30\linewidth}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}&
    {\includegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} &
    Some text 
    \end{tabular}
```

and the image of output.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10):

Loading the `adjustbox` package lets you write `valign=c` or `valign=t` etc when doing an `\includegraphics{...}` command.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c c |p{0.30\linewidth}}
    {\includegraphics[valign=t, width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}&
    {\includegraphics[valign=t, width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} &
    Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\vspace{0pt}` to get an invisible line for the vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*2{>{\vspace{0pt}}p{0.3\linewidth}}|>{\vspace{0pt}}p{0.3\linewidth}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}  &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{BoAwithNO} &
    Some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use nested tabular environments within the table, for the graphics files.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}



\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{c c |p{0.30\linewidth}}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} 
\end{tabular} 
& some text \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just introduce `\tincludegraphics` that shifts the image down by its height minus the height of a text strut.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\tincludegraphics[2][]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
Smaller than image size:\\
    \begin{tabular}{c c |p{0.30\linewidth}}
    {\tincludegraphics[height=1in, width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}&
    {\tincludegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} &
    Text
    \end{tabular}

Now larger than image size:\\
    \begin{tabular}{c c |p{0.30\linewidth}}
    {\tincludegraphics[height=.5in,width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}&
    {\tincludegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} &
    \scriptsize\lipsum[4]
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If centered images were desired, I define `\cincludegraphics`...
And rather than using a `p` column, I used a `\parbox` with the `[c]` centering option.  In this way, the text and images will always be centered relative to each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\cincludegraphics[2][]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
Smaller than image size:\\
    \begin{tabular}{c c |c}
    {\cincludegraphics[height=1in, width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}&
    {\cincludegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} &
    \parbox{0.30\linewidth}{Text}
    \end{tabular}

Now larger than image size:\\
    \begin{tabular}{c c |c}
    {\cincludegraphics[height=.5in,width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwoNO2}}&
    {\cincludegraphics[width=0.30\linewidth]{BoAwithNO}} &
    \parbox{0.30\linewidth}{\scriptsize\lipsum[4]}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]